# Rust program to one hot encode genetic sequences from .fa files

Tags: python, rust, bioinformatics

I wanted to write some code which reads in a [FASTA file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) and one hot encodes the sequence which is consequentially saved to a file. A FASTA file is a text based file format commonly used in bioinformatics. Here's an example:

```
>chr1
ACGTCTCGTGC
NNNNNNNNNNN
ACGTTGGGGGG
>chr2
AGGGTCTGGGT
NNNNNNNNNNN
```

It has a header string with `>` and then some genetic sequence following. Every character in that sequence represents a nucleotide. For example "A" stands for Adenine and "N" for unknown. The number of possible characters in the sequence is limited, but there are some encodings allowing different representations. But this is not that important for me, since I will probably filter beforehand anyway.

The output should be a text file with the one hot encoded sequence and the header for identification.  Depending on how one would choose the encoding this could look something like this for the first three nucleotides(`ACG`):

```
>chr1
0,0,0,1
0,1,0,0
0,0,1,0
```

I wrote some Rust code together to achieve this and it works, but it seems to be pretty slow. Maybe I should also mention at this point that the FASTA files can get really big (many GB) in no time. I tried my code (cargo build --release) with an ~60MB .fa file and took about ~1m.30s and some generic Python code I wrote together in 10 minutes took only ~40s.

Now I wanted to know why my Rust Code is slower then it's Python equivalent. Did I write it inn an idiomatic Rust way? I do not want to store the data in something like HDF5. I just want to understand Rust better. Especially I/O heavy text processing tasks, since these are common in bioinformatics.

Here's the code I wrote:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, Write};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::env;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;

fn main()  -> std::io::Result<()>{

    // gather cmd arguments
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect(); 
    let filename: &String = &args[1];
    let outfile: &String = &args[2];

    // Open the file to read from
    let file = File::open(&filename).unwrap();

    // Create a buffered reader -> instead of reading everything to ram
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let lines = reader.lines(); 

    // this allows to open a file in file append mode to write (or create it)
    let mut to_write_file = OpenOptions::new()
        .append(true)
        .create(true) // Optionally create 
        .open(outfile)
        .expect("Unable to open file");

    // iterate over every line
    for l in lines {

        // check if we get a string back (Result<String, Error>)
        if let Ok(line_string) = l {

            // check for header lines
             if line_string.contains("chr"){
                 println!("Processing: {}",line_string);
                 // write to file so we can keep track of chroms
                 writeln!(to_write_file, "{}",line_string).unwrap();
             }
             else {
                 // iterate over nucleotides
                 for character in line_string.chars() {
                     // one hot encode the nucleotide
                     let nucleotide: String = one_hot_encode_string(String::from(character));
                     writeln!(to_write_file,"{}", nucleotide)?;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn one_hot_encode_string(nucleotide: String) -> String {
    // One hot encodes a Nucleotide: String

    let encoding: String; // create return variable

    // OHE the nucleotide
    match nucleotide.as_str() {
    "A" => encoding = String::from("0,0,0,1"),
    "G" => encoding = String::from("0,0,1,0"),
    "C" => encoding = String::from("0,1,0,0"),
    "T" => encoding = String::from("1,0,0,0"),
    "N" => encoding = String::from("0,0,0,0"),
    _ => encoding = String::from("NA"),
    }
    encoding
    
}
```

Her's also the "naive" python code:

```py
import sys
# one hot encode nulceotide
def ohe(nucleotide: str) -> str:
    if nucleotide == "A":
        return("0,0,0,1")
    if nucleotide == "G":
        return("0,0,1,0")
    if nucleotide == "T":
        return("0,1,0,0")
    if nucleotide == "C":
        return("1,0,0,0")
    if nucleotide == "N":
        return("0,0,0,0")
    else:
        return("NA")

def main() -> None:
    # get arguments
    input: str = sys.argv[1]
    output: str = sys.argv[2]

    # open in file
    with open(input) as in_f:
        # open out file
        with open(output, 'a') as out_f:
            for line in in_f:
                # get header
                if line.startswith(">"):
                    out_f.write(f"{line.rstrip()}\n")
                else:
                    # iterate over every nucleotide
                    for character in line.rstrip():
                        # one hot encode character
                        # print(ohe(character))
                        out_f.write(f"{ohe(character)}\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Do you have a good link or summary to what the hot-encoding format is?

Comment: On a modern OS, you shouldn’t worry about “reading the file contents into RAM.” It doesn’t work that way any longer: when you memory-map a file, only the pages that you actually touch will be loaded into physical memory. This is typically faster than copying the data to a buffer.

Comment: @Davislor That is _if_ you memory-map a file. mmap isn't in Rust's standard library.

Comment: @Davislor: Hre's a link to an explanation of [one hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your programs aren't quite equivalent; one looks at whether a line starts with `>`, the other looks for `chr` in each line. That doesn't make much of a difference in the big picture, but the play area should be level, shouldn't it?

Secondly, as I mentioned over on SO, you should probably avoid `String::from` calls wherever possible. Since those one-hot encodings are constant, you can just return a `&'static str`.

Thirdly, and this is the thing that really makes all the difference, your Python program is implicitly using buffered writes instead of directly writing to the output file every time.

Wrapping `to_write_file` in a `BufReader::new` makes quite the difference, see below.
`u60.fasta` is an arbitrary 60 megabyte FASTA file.

### original

```
(original) $ time cargo run --release -- u60.fasta /dev/null
   Compiling cr272415 v0.1.0 (/Users/akx/build/cr272415)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.35s
     Running `target/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null`
Processing: >NC_000001.11 Homo sapiens chromosome 1, GRCh38.p13 Primary Assembly

________________________________________________________
Executed in    6.66 secs    fish           external
   usr time    4.74 secs  113.00 micros    4.74 secs
   sys time    2.44 secs  799.00 micros    2.44 secs
```

### optimized

```
~/b/cr272415 (master) $ time cargo run --release -- u60.fasta /dev/null
   Compiling cr272415 v0.1.0 (/Users/akx/build/cr272415)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.38s
     Running `target/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null`
Processing: >NC_000001.11 Homo sapiens chromosome 1, GRCh38.p13 Primary Assembly

________________________________________________________
Executed in  650.30 millis    fish           external
   usr time    1.21 secs    147.00 micros    1.21 secs
   sys time    0.17 secs    939.00 micros    0.16 secs
```

I'm not an experienced Rustacean, so someone can probably improve on this, but the `optimized` version is below. Some of the changes were suggested by `cargo clippy` (which you should also heed :-) ).

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, BufWriter, Write};

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    // gather cmd arguments
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let filename: &String = &args[1];
    let outfile: &String = &args[2];

    // Open the file to read from
    let file = File::open(&filename).unwrap();

    // Create a buffered reader -> instead of reading everything to ram
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let lines = reader.lines();

    // this allows to open a file in file append mode to write (or create it)
    let mut to_write_file = BufWriter::new(
        OpenOptions::new()
            .append(true)
            .create(true) // Optionally create
            .open(outfile)
            .expect("Unable to open file"),
    );

    // iterate over every line
    for line_string in lines.flatten() {
        // check for header lines
        if line_string.starts_with('>') {
            println!("Processing: {}", line_string);
            // write to file so we can keep track of chroms
            writeln!(to_write_file, "{}", line_string).unwrap();
        } else {
            // iterate over nucleotides
            for character in line_string.chars() {
                // one hot encode the nucleotide
                let nucleotide = one_hot_encode_string(character);
                writeln!(to_write_file, "{}", nucleotide)?;
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn one_hot_encode_string(nucleotide: char) -> &'static str {
    // One hot encodes a Nucleotide character
    match nucleotide {
        'A' => "0,0,0,1",
        'G' => "0,0,1,0",
        'C' => "0,1,0,0",
        'T' => "1,0,0,0",
        'N' => "0,0,0,0",
        _ => "NA",
    }
}
```

## Edit ⚡️

Some background thread in my brain realized one more way to make this faster still: don't use `writeln!`. There's no need to spend time parsing format strings and allocating memory just to add a newline. If you precompose the `\n` into the output, you can just use `BufWriter.write_all()` – i.e. change the end of the program above to

```rust
                let nucleotide = one_hot_encode_string(character);
                to_write_file.write_all(nucleotide.as_ref())?;
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn one_hot_encode_string(nucleotide: char) -> &'static str {
    // One hot encodes a Nucleotide character
    match nucleotide {
        'A' => "0,0,0,1\n",
        'G' => "0,0,1,0\n",
        'C' => "0,1,0,0\n",
        'T' => "1,0,0,0\n",
        'N' => "0,0,0,0\n",
        _ => "NA\n",
    }
}
```

A benchmark run with [`hyperfine`](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) speaks more than a thousand words, as they say:

```
~/b/cr272415 (master) $ hyperfine --warmup 3 './original/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null' './opt1/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null' './opt2/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null'
Benchmark 1: ./original/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null
  Time (mean ± σ):      6.401 s ±  0.441 s    [User: 4.004 s, System: 2.385 s]
  Range (min … max):    5.978 s …  7.292 s    10 runs

Benchmark 2: ./opt1/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null
  Time (mean ± σ):     170.8 ms ±   4.2 ms    [User: 167.0 ms, System: 2.8 ms]
  Range (min … max):   164.5 ms … 178.4 ms    17 runs

Benchmark 3: ./opt2/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null
  Time (mean ± σ):      59.2 ms ±   2.0 ms    [User: 55.8 ms, System: 2.5 ms]
  Range (min … max):    56.5 ms …  65.6 ms    45 runs

Summary
  './opt2/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null' ran
    2.89 ± 0.12 times faster than './opt1/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null'
  108.21 ± 8.29 times faster than './original/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null'
```

## Edit ⚡️ x 2

One more thing I realized (though this could turn out to be CPU cache-inefficient in a larger program): inline the whole darned write call, and mark the constants as bytestrings to avoid `.as_ref()` altogether. Hyperfine says this is `1.32 ± 0.11 times faster than opt2` (the above edit).

```
macro_rules! wf {
    ($s:expr) => {
        to_write_file.write_all($s)
    };
}
for character in line_string.chars() {
    match character {
        'A' => wf!(b"0,0,0,1\n"),
        'G' => wf!(b"0,0,1,0\n"),
        'C' => wf!(b"0,1,0,0\n"),
        'T' => wf!(b"1,0,0,0\n"),
        'N' => wf!(b"0,0,0,0\n"),
        _ => wf!(b"NA\n"),
    }
    .unwrap();
}
```

```
~/b/cr272415 (vecw *) $ ./bench.sh
Benchmark 1: ./targets/original/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null
  Time (mean ± σ):      6.294 s ±  0.182 s    [User: 3.942 s, System: 2.340 s]
  Range (min … max):    6.060 s …  6.592 s    10 runs

Benchmark 2: ./targets/opt1/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null
  Time (mean ± σ):     176.7 ms ±   6.9 ms    [User: 172.1 ms, System: 3.2 ms]
  Range (min … max):   166.1 ms … 188.5 ms    16 runs

Benchmark 3: ./targets/opt2/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null
  Time (mean ± σ):      61.5 ms ±   2.9 ms    [User: 57.8 ms, System: 2.6 ms]
  Range (min … max):    58.4 ms …  73.8 ms    43 runs

Benchmark 4: ./targets/vecw/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null
  Time (mean ± σ):      46.0 ms ±   2.9 ms    [User: 42.6 ms, System: 2.5 ms]
  Range (min … max):    42.2 ms …  55.7 ms    60 runs

Summary
  './targets/vecw/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null' ran
    1.33 ± 0.11 times faster than './targets/opt2/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null'
    3.84 ± 0.29 times faster than './targets/opt1/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null'
  136.71 ± 9.55 times faster than './targets/original/release/cr272415 u60.fasta /dev/null'
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I implemented your changes and it runs on my machine about 2s now. This is phenomenal. And thank you for the clippy suggestions. I did not know about it. My only question would be why do we have to make the return of the one_hot_encode_string function `&'static str`? The Rust documentation says it's reference with static lifetime. But wouldn't a normal `str` work too? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `&'static str` is the type of a string literal in code. `str` has no compile-time-known size (since it's really a slice), so it can't be used by itself. (You could try – the compiler will complain that you simply can't.)

Comment: That made it clear. Thank you!

Comment: @dry-leaf Hey, I figured out one more way to make things even faster - see my edit :)

Comment: Tbh, I am really impressed. I did not expect to get such a serious performance boost. This is something I did not think about all, while beeing quite obvious. Thank you very much for this insight. This will prove useful not just here, but also in future projects! :)

Comment: Do you know whether it makes a real difference if I would use `to_write_file.write_all(nucleotide.as_bytes())?;` rather as `.as_ref()`?. Both work fine.

Comment: [There's no real difference – `.as_ref()` calls `.as_bytes()`.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b70cc6422c141191aeb33f5ab6faba992118812b/library/core/src/str/mod.rs#L2471-L2477)

Comment: @dry-leaf In case you missed it, I figured out one more optimization that squeezes even more performance out of it, at the expense of repetition in code :)

Comment: Thank you!  That helped immensely!